# How to create file with text in every subfolder?

Tags: files, directory-structure

For example I have a hierarchy `a/b/c`. How do I crate a file with name `d.txt`  and text `"Hello World"` in every folder `a`, `a/b` and `a/b/c`?

Comment: Smells like homework...

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
echo Hello World > a{,/b{,/c}}/d.txt
```

Or for all non-hidden dirs that happen to be found here via a recursive search:

```
dirs=(**/*(/))
echo Hello World > $^dirs/d.txt
```

That involves an internal `tee` so the output is written to all files at the same time. If there's a large number of files, you may run into a limit of number of opened file in which case you may want to write that content in sequence, one file at a time:

```
for d ($dirs) echo Hello World > $d/d.txt
```

The standard equivalent would be something like:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . \( -name '.*' -prune -o -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    echo Hello World > "$dir/d.txt"
  done' sh {} + \)
```

- `LC_ALL=C` so that `-name '.*'` matches on all files that start with `.`, not just those that start with `.` and are followed by a sequence of valid characters.
- `! -name .` excludes the current directory as we want only **sub**-folders (and also not want to prune `.`)
- `-name '.*' -prune`, excludes hidden files and also prevents `find` from descending into  hidden directories.
- `-o`: if not (*or*)
- `-type d` select only files of type *directory*.
- `-exec sh -c 'inline-script' sh {} +`: pass the list of matching dirs to an inline script.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . -type d -exec /bin/bash -c 'echo "Hello world" >'{}'/d.txt' \;
```

Comment: Maybe `find /a`...?